# Variable substitution in sed/bash

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I'm trying to do variable substitution in sed/bash.

I have seen this example available [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69112/how-can-i-use-variables-when-doing-a-sed), but it does not replace the data as required. The value observed in line 20 of $C_CONF is `$RAM`, when I want it to be `100`.

Line 20 of `$C_CONF` is `AllowedRAMSpace=SomeValue` and I would like to change that value on-the-fly.

This is the trick I created, but it is a very ugly and inefficient one.

```
 32 for RAM in 100 #80 60 40 20
 33 do  
 34     sudo sed -i -re 's/(AllowedRAMSpace=)[^=]*$/\1"'"$RAM"'"/' $C_CONF
 35     sudo sed -i '20s/"//' $C_CONF
 36     sudo sed -i '20s/"//' $C_CONF 
 37 done
```

What is the other way?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem here. `sed -re 's/(AllowedRAMSpace=)[^=]*$/\1'"$RAM"'/'` works like a charm and renders your other `sed` commands useless.

Comment: Looks like that's the trick. I had an additional `"`. If you paste that as the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using awk instead

```
awk 'BEGIN{RAM=100}NR==20{print gensub(/(AllowedRAMSpace=)([^=].*$)/,"\\1"RAM,"g", $0)}' filename
```